# Getting x amount of rows where id = id(other table) with the highest amount of rows with that id

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

x = doesn't matter

table A

```
0 row0
1 row1
2 row2
```

table B

```
0 x
1 x
0 X
2 X
2 X
0 x
```

there are in this example 3 rows of 0, 2 rows of 2 and 1 row 1.

i want to get for example the two rows who has the highest count of rows.

desired result:

```
0 row0 ==> because 3 rows in b is the highest amount.
2 row2 ==> because 2 rows in b is the second highest amount.
```

my attempt so far:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM A
WHERE Id =
(
SELECT IdB FROM B
GROUP BY IdB 
ORDER BY count(IdB) DESC
LIMIT 2
)
```

edit: i use mysql

thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i use mysql as database.

Comment: Instead of `WHERE =` use `WHERE IN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to `JOIN` your tables together by `id`:

```
SELECT
  A.id,
  A.name
FROM
  A join
  B on A.id = B.id
GROUP BY
  A.name
ORDER BY
  count(B.id) desc
LIMIT 2
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2c7c/1)

That will return an output that matches your example above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want to handle ties.

What this does is JOIN ([learn more about joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)) the two tables together based on your ID's  then aggregate the results counting the occurrences of B.IDB and displaying that count along with the name from table A

```
SELECT A.Name, count(B.IDB) cnt
FROM A
INNER JOIN IDB
 on A.ID = B.IDB
GROUP BY A.Name
ORDER BY count(B.IDB) desc
LIMIT 2
```

But with your example this should return

```
Name cnt
row0 3
row2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

-- Sample table

-- table A schema

```
create table A (id int, name varchar(10))

 insert into A 
 values (0, 'row0')
  insert into A 
 values (1, 'row1')
 insert into A 
 values (2, 'row2')

 select * from A
```

-- table A schema

```
 create table B (id int, name varchar(10))

 insert into B 
 values (0, 'X')
 insert into B 
 values (0, 'X')
 insert into B 
 values (0, 'X')
 insert into B 
 values (0, 'X')
   insert into B 
 values (1, 'X')
 insert into B 
 values (2, 'X')
 insert into B 
 values (2, 'X')
 insert into B 
 values (2, 'X')
 insert into B 
 values (2, 'X')
 insert into B 
 values (2, 'X')
 insert into B 
 values (2, 'X')

 select * from B
```

--Query

```
 select Top 2 A.name, count(B.id) from A
  inner join B on A.id = b.id
   group by A.name
 order by  count(A.name) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try ;

```
select a.name, b.count
  from A a,
       (select idB, count(idB) count from B group by idB) b
 where a.id = b.idB
   and count > 1
```